# Browse firefox history without refresh

Tags: firefox, history

If I browse the firefox history and click on a link say `foo.com`, the site opens and `foo.com` jumps to the top of the list and all other items above the old position of `foo.com` goes one item down. This makes sense since firefox needs to update the history if I open `foo.com` again, but it is sometimes very annoying that the list rearranges.

So how can I browse the history without changing the history, i.e. browse a "freezed" version of the history? However the "freezed" version should remain searchable in the sense that it narrows down the links if you provide a search pattern. However it shouldn't rearrange in any way the order of the links if you click on it.

I also need a antichronological order in the freezed version.

Comment: Browsing that history website in incognito mode may not alter that history position.

Comment: The only method I know is to use an add-on that offers this feature.

Comment: @Biswa confirmed. Switching to New Private Window allows you to revisit links in History without changing the list.

Comment: @Biswa: Thanks, that solves the problem. Maybe you can convert it to an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this - browse in private browsing mode.

To turn on private browsing mode use the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or go to Menu > New Private Browsing Window:
[image]

As you can see from this screenshot below - when you open a previous history entry in normal browsing mode - the entry jumps to the top of the list:
[image]

As you can see from the screenshot below - when performing the same action in private browsing mode - this entry stays where it is:
[image]

As a final test - switching back to normal browsing mode and opening your history doesn't show the reloaded entry from private browsing (although if it did, it wouldn't exactly be private browsing would it?!):[image]